# How to collect and publish input from user, using webform and views?

Tags: views, forms, webforms

I want to build a form, with a lot of fields that can collect data from a lot of users.
than, I want to have the option to play with this data and publish it through views (with sorting options).

How to do that (general steps)?

This is what it tried so far:

I built a new content type, with a few specific fields, that allow me to publish all the data in a lot of ways through views. but, I don't know how to make a form from this content type and these fields, in order to allow anonymous and other users to insert data.

and if I use webform module, I can collect data from users, but I don't know how to publish this data through views (if this possible at all).

Comment: OK, I will rephrase my question a little.
I used the entity form, and created a great form, with a lot of fields. than, I entered a lot of content to those fields.
But, and this is what I didn't understand, the information I entered to the entity form, didn't became "Content" (or maybe node is the right word?).
Any way, what I am trying to do is to create a form, with a lot of special fields, where users (any user - even anonymous) can enter information. then I want this data to be "content" (that can be found on the content tab on the administration bar).

Answer (score 1):

For web-form refer to the link http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/build-styled-user-feedback-form-webform-drupal-7

And for view you can create node pages and give the permissions to the user to be able to create the node page....

Answer (score 1):

Achieving that can be reached in many ways, I would divide it to the following steps:

**Steps are:**

1. Collect data.
2. Manipulate data.
3. Outpting the data.

There is a lot of ways to collect data, I disagree with using node for that, You want to collect data only, you don't need any features of the node itself.

I will also avoid [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module because it will its own fields (not core fields) and it's a bit more complicated to display the data with the right handlers in views.

I would recommend here [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module, You can build form easily and have your data stored.

Manipulating the data can be done by using standard entity hooks or directly using [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

The publish option is simply boolean field where its checked or not, and filter that in your view to show only entities which marked as published.

Using views you can easily output your data (Filtered with publish field)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [entityforms](http://drupal.org/project/entityform) or [webform_entity](http://drupal.org/project/webform_entity)?

From entityform:

> The Entityforms module enables you to create front-end forms
>   (fieldable entities), which contain fields that you define! These
>   forms use the standard Drupal fields.

From webform_entity:

> This module exposes webform submissions as a fieldable entity on
>   behalf of webform and optionally provides a bundle for each of the
>   content types for which webform functionality is enabled. This allows
>   you to configure fields on a base form that are appended to the fields
>   for the webform for that individual node and these fields can be
>   exposed to views.

These 2 modules are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new content type form collecting information from user. Set the permission for create content by anonymous user.
Then using the view you can display the content.